# How to use gsub() to partially match part of a string and replace all strings containing that partial match?

Tags: r

I am trying to look for the word 'dunk' in a column of NBA shot types as there are various types of dunks.

Then replace all the different dunk types with just the word 'dunk'

```
nbaClean2 <- nbaData %>% 
    select(x, y, points, type, result, team, player) %>% 
    filter(team == 'LAL', y <= 47) %>% 
    na_if("") %>% 
    drop_na() %>% 
    mutate(result = ifelse(result == 'missed', 'FGA', 'FGM')) %>% 
    mutate(dunk = gsub('\bdunk', 'dunk', type))
    mutate(dunk = grepl('dunk', type), gsub('TRUE', 'dunk', dunk))
```

Essentially trying to see if I can use gsub() to partial match the word 'dunk'.

Trying to find a solution where I don't have to write all different types of shot types down if possible as there is a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` will only replace the match. You can make the match match the full string by wrapping it in `.*`, which matches anything.

```
mutate(dunk = gsub('.*dunk.*', 'dunk', type))
```

(Note I got rid of your `\b` word boundary. If you want to use it, you'd need a double backslash `".*\\bdunk.*"`, but then you wouldn't match anything that *doesn't* have a word boundary before dunk, e.g., `"slamdunk"` would not match.)

A potentially more efficient option would be to detect the `"dunk"` pattern and then replace the whole string without regex, e.g.

```
mutate(dunk = ifelse(grepl("dunk", type, fixed = TRUE), "dunk", "not dunk"))
```

It's not clear what value you want in the newly created `dunk` column when `type` doesn't include `"dunk"`. I'd consider making it a logical column simply with `dunk = grepl("dunk", type)`. If you post sample input and desired output it much easier to help. Perhaps you don't want a `dunk` column at all, but just to change `type` to "dunk" if it includes the word "dunk", like this: `mutate(type = ifelse(grepl("dunk", type), "dunk", type))`.